# F12 Developer Tools \ Network : duplicate js files with '?_=1353604295011' behind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, caching, browser-cache

I am working on caching data on my Visual Studio 2012 MVC4 website. I analyse network traffic from F12 Developer Tools. I can see that data is cached but I didn't understand the red surrounded part (see below). It seems to be redundant.

[image]

So for example the /Contact/Index.js is cached (304)

But /Contact/Index.js?_=1353604295011 is not cached (200) and seems to be the same file?

Does someone can explain me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We encountered a similar issue.  Do you have JavaScript includes inside a DOM element that is being manipulated? If you are rewriting part of the DOM that has script tags within, it will reload those JavaScript tags in the exact manner that you are mentioning.

The ?_= appended to the end of the URL is a Unix epoch designed to break the cache.